# How to use two .cpp files in a project (class)?

Tags: c++

How to use two .cpp files in a project?

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "second.h"
int main () {
    secondFunction();
}
```

`second.h`:

```
void secondFunction();
```

`second.cpp`:

```
#include "second.h"
void secondFunction() {
   // do stuff
}
```

It works, but when I use class it doesn't work.

`empoyee.h`:

```
class employee {
public:
void paymentmethod();
};
```

`employee.cpp`:

```
 #include "employee.h"
 void employee::paymentmethod() {
 //code
   }
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "employee.h"
main()
{  employee em;
 em.paymentmethod()

}
```

I had figured out error in .cpp declaration.

Comment: It's hard telling what could be wrong without looking at the contents of the Makefile. Please post the contents of the Makefile.

Comment: Did you omit the inclusion of employee.h in main.cpp? Also please post the error message

Comment: Welcome to SO! First of all, "help me solve this" is not a question, but an inappropriate imperative. Second, it appears your post does not include the complete error message, that makes it difficult to tell what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do but here are some tips:

- Every header file should include all headers that you are going to use for that file or class.
- Every cpp file that corresponds to a particular header file should include ONLY that header file.
- Your main.cpp should include all headers that you are using for your program.

Your code should look something like this:

```
// main.cpp
#include "second.h"
#include "employee.h"

int main(){
//code
}
```

In your other files:

```
//second.h

//includes here
void function();
//---------------------------------------------

//second.cpp
#include "second.h"

void function(){ //code }

//---------------------------------------------

//employee.h

//includes here

class employee{
public:
     void payment();
//ctor, dtor, and other declarations
}

//---------------------------------------------

//employee.cpp

#include "employee.h"

void employee::payment(){ //code }

//rest of methods
```

Unfortunately, there will be build problems if you include the same header more than once in the same program. So for all header files, you should implement this guard:

```
#ifndef __MYCLASS_H__
#define __MYCLASS_H__

//includes

class MyClass{
//declarations
}

#endif
```

Comment: I disagree on points 2 and 3: **2** .cpp files may very well need things from other headers not needed in their corresponding header. **3** The main file should, like all others, only include what it *needs*.

Comment: I see your point about cpp files needing headers not in their corresponding headers, but I personally put everything I will need for my cpp in the corresponding header. The cpp should be free of declarations, includes, and any other preprocessor directives. The cpp should simply contain code. That's how I learned though. And the Google C++ Style guide doesn't seem to care how this is done particularly. It just says, "any includes present in the related header do not need to be included again in the related cc (i.e., foo.cc can rely on foo.h's includes)."